# Why PATH environment variable value is different if we open command prompt from different locations?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, windows-registry, environment-variables

I have a package which adds and removes an entry (say `C:\my_entry`) to PATH environment variable during installation and uninstallation respectively. I am able to see that entry is being added/removed to/from PATH variable by verifying the registry key

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path
```

But I observed different values for PATH environment variable from command prompt.

**After installation**

If I open command prompt as <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, Type `cmd` and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I am able to see `C:\my_entry` in PATH variable.

If I open command prompt(cmd.exe) from `C:\Windows\System32` directory, I am unable to `C:\my_entry` in PATH variable.

**After un-installation**

If I open command prompt as <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd` and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I am still able to see `C:\my_entry` in PATH variable though it got removed from registry.

Please let me know why PATH environment variable value is different if we open command prompt from different locations? And why the PATH environment variable value is different in command prompt from the value present in Registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are usually *inherited* – a new process gets a copy from whatever launched it, *not* from the registry. (ProcExp or Process Hacker can show the env of each individual process, along with the actual hierarchy.)

The only times the registry keys are read are when you log in, and when some program (such as an installer) tells all apps to refresh their env. (Usually only Explorer reacts to that request.)

So it could be that one Explorer process (the one handling the taskbar shell) refreshed its environment after installation, but the one handling folder windows didn't. (Or maybe you ran cmd from a third-party file manager.)